# SelectedItem doesn't bind in ListView in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, data-binding

I've been trying to `Bind` the two `ListViews` to `ViewModel`. Both lists are loading the items properly. But to my surprise I've encountered a little problem.

The first `ListView`'s `SelectedItem` binds correctly but the second one doesn't bind! As shown in the image below. What could be the reason?

[image]

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="Test.Dialogs.BeamElevationsWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:Test.Dialogs.Converters"
        Title="Select Beam Elevation" Height="350" Width="460"
        Style="{StaticResource DialogStyle}"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Window.Resources>
        <converters:ElevationValueConverter x:Key="ElevationValueConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid Margin="10">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <GroupBox>
            <Grid Margin="5">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="175"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="215"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <GroupBox Header="Typs">
                    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding TypIds}"
                              SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentTypId}">
                        <ListView.View>
                            <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False"  
                          ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource DialogsGridViewColumnHeaderStyle}" >
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Typ."/>
                            </GridView>
                        </ListView.View>
                    </ListView>
                </GroupBox>

                <GroupBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Header="Elevations">
                    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Elevations}"
                              SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentBeamElevation}">
                        <ListView.View>
                            <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False"  
                          ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource DialogsGridViewColumnHeaderStyle}" >
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Typ." />
                            </GridView>
                        </ListView.View>
                    </ListView>
                </GroupBox>
            </Grid>
        </GroupBox>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <Button Content="OK"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Code-Behind:**

```
public partial class BeamElevationsWindow
{
    private BeamElevationsViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }

    public BeamElevationsWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ViewModel = new BeamElevationsViewModel();
        DataContext = ViewModel;
    }
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
namespace Test.Dialogs.ViewModels
{
    public class BeamElevationsViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public BeamElevationsViewModel()
        {
            var frames = Building.Frames
                .GroupBy(f => f.TypId)
                .Select(group => group.First())
                .OrderBy(f => f.TypId)
                .ToList();

            typIds = new List<int>();
            foreach (var frame in frames)
            {
                typIds.Add(frame.TypId);
            }

            TypIds = typIds;
            CurrentTypId = Building.CurrentFrame.TypId;

            GetElevations(CurrentTypId);
            CurrentBeamElevation = Building.CurrentBeamElevation;
        }

        public void GetElevations(int typId)
        {
            var frames = Building.Frames
                .Where(f => f.TypId == typId)
                .OrderByDescending(f => f.Elevation)
                .ToList();

            elevations = new List<Elevation>();
            foreach (var fr in frames)
            {
                foreach (var elevation in Building.Elevations)
                {
                    if (Math.Abs(fr.Elevation - elevation.El) < Arithmetics.Tolerance)
                    {
                        elevations.Add(elevation);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            Elevations = elevations;
        }

        private List<int> typIds;
        public List<int> TypIds
        {
            get { return typIds; }
            private set
            {
                typIds = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("TypIds");
            }
        }

        private int currentTypId;
        public int CurrentTypId
        {
            get { return currentTypId; }
            private set
            {
                currentTypId = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentTypId");
            }
        }

        private List<Elevation> elevations;
        public List<Elevation> Elevations
        {
            get { return elevations; }
            private set
            {
                elevations = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Elevations");
            }
        }

        private Elevation currentBeamElevation;
        public Elevation CurrentBeamElevation
        {
            get { return currentBeamElevation; }
            private set
            {
                currentBeamElevation = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentBeamElevation");
            }
        }

        private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing in what you are showing indicates an error. Given the large amount of code, could you be a bit more specific as to what you are expecting vs. what you are seeing?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Thanks Bradley for your interest, as you can see the left ListView's SelectedItem is bound correctly and [1] is selected. But the right ListView's SelectedItem is not bound correctly and nothing is selected!

Comment: Ok, thanks for that clarification. I *think* the issue is the equality check, could you tell me if `Building.CurrentElevation` is the *exact same object* as one in the list? Or does it just have equal properties?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Do you mean `Building.CurrentBeamElevation`? It is type of `Elevation`, the same as list.

Comment: Right, its the same *type*, but is it actually the same *instance*? As in, when you populate the list, is that *actual instance* also in the list?

Comment: Oh I got what you mean, I'm afraid it is not the same instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The binding is actually working fine :)

However, the default comparer for `object` does a *reference* comparison. That means that when its trying to find the existing object in the list, it doesn't pick any of them because they aren't the same instance (per your comment).

The solution is to override `Object.Equals` (and when you override that, you should also override `Object.GetHashCode`). It should test equality based on some unique property of the object, so you don't get false positives.

Comment: Thank you so much Bradley, you hit the nail! That totally solved my problem. `Building.CurrentBeamElevation` was different from the items in the list. I know this may be a code smell but for now I did a little hack to return the selected item from the list using `LINQ` and bind the SelectedItem to it!

Comment: @Vahid I would have just done the `Equals` override, its probably easier, and definitely less bug prone. Glad you got it working though!

Comment: You mean the `Equals` method of `Elevation` class?

Comment: @Vahid Yes, that method override (`Object.Equals`) for that class